# Google data studio and big query

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a question regarding handling dates in google data studio, when the source is one custom query from bigquery. My query result looks something like this, with products A,B,C. I have sales for each date and each product:

| Date | Product | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | A | 1500 |
| 2020-01-02 | A | 2500 |
| 2020-01-03 | A | 2200 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-02-27 | A | 2800 |
| 2021-02-28 | A | 1900 |

What I struggle with:
Directly in my query I already have parameters so I can filter by the products from a drop down list. But I also need to have a date comparison, and my tried approach doesn't seem to work.

What I need:
I want to make a line graph to compare two periods. I know I can use the period comparison setting, but it doesn't give me the flexibility I need.
For example I would like it to return 2022-02-02 and 2022-01-02 as a comparison line.

In the best of worlds I would like to connect it to a new parameter where I set a drop down list for "last month, "six months ago" "one year ago". But I can also have these in separate graphs.

My approach so far:
I am a bit new to this and still unsure how date paramters work. I tried to make a calculated field like this, but it doesn't seem to be supported:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN order_date >= @ds_start_date AND order_date <= @ds_end_date THEN Sales END)
```

I also thought about putting it in a case statement and self join in the query to get the sums between these dates, but will that work when displaying it as a comparison? I want the comparison date to be shown on that line, just like it doesn't when you add a data comparison normally.

I really appreciate if someone could walk me through how I can achieve the result I need. Thank you.